# Create bacpac from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, bacpac

Is it possible to export bacpac file from SQL SERVER 2008 (running 10.50.6220)? I can only see option for dacpac.

Comment: SQL Server v10.50.x is SQL Server **2008 R2** (not **2008** ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sql Database Migration Wizard or command line tool `sqlpackage.exe` for creating `.bacpac` file for SQL Server 2008.

Download + documentation for SQL Database Migration wizard:

https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com

This is from Migration Wizard page, which mentions about supporting SQL Server 2008 version. Though in the download links it only starts from SQL Server 2008 R2 but I would give that a try. I have not tested anything below SQL Server 2012.

> SQL Database Migration Wizard (SQLAzureMW) is designed to help you
>   migrate your SQL Server 2005/2008/2012/2014 databases to Azure SQL
>   Database.

How to use `sqlpackage.exe`?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

There is a step by step [guide](http://video.ch9.ms/sessions/teched/eu/2014/Labs/DBI-H336.pdf) about using these tools.

Answer (score 0):

AS per MSDN BOL [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/dac-support-for-sql-server-objects-and-versions) The fidelity limitations in the DAC Framework data deployment engine in `SQL Server 2012 SP1`. The limitations apply to the following DAC Framework actions: deploy or publish a `.dacpac file`, and import a `.bacpac` file.

For further ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847189/azure-sql-database-bacpac-local-restore